# Angular FORM, removing from DOM doesn't remove at specified index but removes last item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, dom

So, I happen to have a problem where the wrong thing is being deleted from the `DOM`. In the `onDelete()` method, I delete the `FormControl` at the specified index. When I debugged it, `TypeScript` removes the correct value, but in the DOM, the last value pushed is deleted.

So, let's say:

(delete button removes `formControl` from `formArray` and is linked to `onDelete()`)

1. [some input box] [delete button] <- when I press this button
2. [some other input box] [delete button]
3. [some other input box] [delete button] <- this gets removed even when in TypeScript the first value gets removed.

**TypeScript:**

```
export class RecipeAddComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  recipeForm!: FormGroup;
  selectedFile?: File;
  private editModeSub!: Subscription;
  public isEditMode: boolean = false;
  private recipeId?: number;
  selectedFileUrl!: string | ArrayBuffer | null | undefined;
  defaultImageSource: string =
    'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ilYQWb6p_RYzTqdDqoTjqAHaHa?w=198&h=198&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.editModeSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  constructor(
    private readonly _recipeService: RecipeService,
    private readonly _navigator: Router,
    public dialog: Dialog,
    private readonly _route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  get ingredientControls() {
    return (this.recipeForm.get('ingredients') as FormArray).controls;
  }

  get stepControls() {
    return (this.recipeForm.get('steps') as FormArray).controls;
  }

  get prepTimes() {
    return (this.recipeForm.get('prepTimes') as FormArray).controls;
  }

  private initForm() {
    //TODO this one probably needs refactor haha
    let title = '';
    let description = '';
    let recipeImg: File;
    let servings = '';
    let servingsYield = '';

    let ingredients;
    let steps;
    let prepTimes;

    this.editModeSub = this._recipeService.bhSubject.subscribe((value) => {
      this.recipeId = value.recipeId;
      this.isEditMode = value.isEditMode;
      this._recipeService.bhSubject.complete();
      this._recipeService.bhSubject = new BehaviorSubject<{
        isEditMode: boolean;
        recipeId: number;
      }>(null!);
    });

    if (!this.isEditMode) {
      ingredients = new FormArray([
        new FormControl('e.g. 2 spoons of sugar powder', Validators.required),
        new FormControl('e.g. 1 cup of flour', Validators.required),
        new FormControl('e.g. 2 eggs', Validators.required),
      ]);
      steps = new FormArray([
        new FormControl(
          'e.g. Preheat oven to 350degrees C...',
          Validators.required
        ),
        new FormControl(
          'e.g. Combine all dry ingredients in a large bowl..',
          Validators.required
        ),
      ]);
      prepTimes = new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          title: new FormControl('Prep Time', Validators.required),
          time: new FormControl(0, Validators.required),
          unit: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        }),
        new FormGroup({
          title: new FormControl('Cook Time', Validators.required),
          time: new FormControl(0, Validators.required),
          unit: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        }),
      ]);
    } else {
      ingredients = new FormArray<FormControl>([]);
      steps = new FormArray([]);
      prepTimes = new FormArray([]);
      this._recipeService.fetchRecipe(this.recipeId).subscribe((recipe) => {
        this.recipeForm.patchValue(recipe);
        //TODO 3 fors just doesn't look right but it works now REFACTOR
        for (const ingredient of recipe.ingredients) {
          ingredients.push(new FormControl(ingredient, Validators.required));
        }
        for (const step of recipe.steps) {
          steps.push(new FormControl(step, Validators.required));
        }
        for (const prepTime of recipe.prepTimes) {
          prepTimes.push(
            new FormGroup({
              title: new FormControl(prepTime.title, Validators.required),
              time: new FormControl(prepTime.time, Validators.required),
              unit: new FormControl(prepTime.unit, Validators.required),
            })
          );
        }
      });
    }

    this.recipeForm = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(title, Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(description, Validators.required),
      imageFile: new FormControl(recipeImg!),
      servings: new FormControl(servings, Validators.required),
      servingsYield: new FormControl(servingsYield),
      ingredients: ingredients,
      steps: steps,
      prepTimes: prepTimes,
    });
  }

  onAddTime() {
    (this.recipeForm.get('prepTimes') as FormArray).push(
      new FormGroup({
        title: new FormControl(),
        time: new FormControl(),
        unit: new FormControl(),
      })
    );
  }

  // TODO suddenly this doesn't removeAt index but removes last in the DOM
  onDelete(index: number, controlName: string) {
    (this.recipeForm.get(controlName) as FormArray).removeAt(index);
  }

  onAdd(controlName: string, name: string) {
    (this.recipeForm.get(controlName) as FormArray).push(
      new FormControl('Add another ' + name, Validators.required)
    );
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mx-auto p2 root-container">
  <form [formGroup]="recipeForm" class="form-margin" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div>
      <p>some paragraph here</p>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="tdp-containter">
      <div>
        <div class="input-container">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <mat-label>Recipe title</mat-label>
            <input
              matInput
              type="text"
              placeholder="Give your recipe a title"
              formControlName="title"
            />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
            <textarea
              matInput
              type="text"
              placeholder="Share the story behind your recipe!"
              formControlName="description"
            ></textarea>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="file"
          (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
          class="file-input"
          formControlName="imageFile"
          #fileInput
        />
        <button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">
          <img
            class="img-fluid"
            [src]="selectedFileUrl ? selectedFileUrl : defaultImageSource"
            alt="Selected Image"
          />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <h5>Ingredietns</h5>
    <p>
      Enter one ingredient per line. Include the quantity (i.e. cups,
      tablespoons) and any special preparation (i.e. sifted, softened, chopped).
      Use optional headers to organize the different parts of the recipe (i.e.
      Cake, Frosting, Dressing).
    </p>
    @for (item of ingredientControls; track $index) {
    <div formArrayName="ingredients">
      <div class="container-with-delete">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Ingredient</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            type="text"
            [placeholder]="item.value"
            [formControlName]="$index"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
        <button type="button" (click)="onDelete($index, 'ingredients')">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    }
    <button type="button" (click)="onAdd('ingredients', 'ingredient')">
      Add Ingredient
    </button>
    <hr />
    <h5>Directions</h5>
    <p>
      Explain how to make your recipe, including oven temperatures, baking or
      cooking times, and pan sizes, etc. Use optional headers to organize the
      different parts of the recipe (i.e. Prep, Bake, Decorate).
    </p>
    @for (item of stepControls; track $index) {
    <div formArrayName="steps">
      <div class="container-with-delete">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Step {{ $index + 1 }}</mat-label>
          <textarea
            matInput
            type="text"
            [placeholder]="item.value"
            [formControlName]="$index"
          ></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button type="button" (click)="onDelete($index, 'steps')">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    }
    <button type="button" (click)="onAdd('steps', 'step')">Add Step</button>
    <hr />
    <div class="container-with-delete">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Servings</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          type="number"
          min="0"
          placeholder="e.g. 8"
          formControlName="servings"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Yield (Optional)</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="e.g. 1 9-inch cake"
          formControlName="servingsYield"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="container-with-delete">
      <div formArrayName="prepTimes">
        @for (item of prepTimes; track $index) {
        <div [formGroupName]="$index">
          @if ($index < 2) {
          <div class="container-with-delete">
            <p>{{ item.get("title")?.value }}</p>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input
                matInput
                type="number"
                min="0"
                placeholder="0"
                formControlName="time"
              />
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="unit">
                <mat-option value="mins">mins</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="hours">hours</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="days">days</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          } @else {
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="title">
              <mat-option value="Freeze">Freeze</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Additional">Additional</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Cool">Cool</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Marinate">Marinate</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Rest">Rest</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Soak">Soak</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input
              matInput
              type="number"
              min="0"
              placeholder="0"
              formControlName="time"
            />
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="unit">
              <mat-option value="mins">mins</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="hours">hours</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="days">days</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <button type="button" (click)="onDelete($index, 'prepTimes')">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
          }
        </div>
        }
        <button type="button" (click)="onAddTime()">Add Time</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <button [disabled]="recipeForm.invalid" type="submit">
      {{ isEditMode ? "Save Changes" : "Submit Recipe" }}
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing @for template syntax, namely the way you iterate ingredients form array on the template:

- track by `item`, not `$index`
- *(optionally: declare separate variable `index`, and send it to the `onDelete` method instead of `$index`)*

try this:

```
  @for (item of ingredientControls; track item; let index = $index;) {
    <div formArrayName="ingredients">
      <div class="container-with-delete">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Ingredient</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            type="text"
            [placeholder]="item.value"
            [formControlName]="index"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
        <button type="button" (click)="onDelete(index, 'ingredients')">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    }
```

source guidelines:

[What is the @for tracking function?](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-for/#what-is-the-for-tracking-function)

> The tracking function created via the track statement is used to make
> it easy for the Angular change detection mechanism to know exactly
> what items to update in the DOM after the input array changes.

edit:

refactor suggestion:

create a separate method to construct form, which always takes an object, which can be default data or data from the server depending on `isEditMode`

- move form creation in the else part into a separate method which constructs form from input object

```
    public constructForm(recipe:any) {
          
          // perhaps change to `this.ingredients`
          // or maybe even return form controls and add them with spread:
          // return {ingredients: ...}
          // and then
          // this.recipeForm = new FormGroup({
          // ...returnedControls,

          ingredients = new FormArray<FormControl>([]);
          steps = new FormArray([]);
          prepTimes = new FormArray([]);
  
         this.recipeForm.patchValue(recipe);

          // for loops
    }
```

- create default data object

  ```
  defaultFormData = {
    ingredients: ['e.g. 2 spoons of sugar powder',...],
    steps: ['e.g. 2 spoons of sugar powder',...]
    // etc.
  };
  ```

- now, depending on `isEditMode`, send either default object, or fetch server object:

```
// send default object
if (!this.isEditMode) {
  this.constructForm(this.defaultFormData);
} else {
  // send server object
  this._recipeService.fetchRecipe(this.recipeId).subscribe((recipe) => {
    this.constructForm(recipe);

}
```

Comment: This worked perfecly! Thank you! By the way could you give a glance at my initForm() method? Since i use this form for adding and editting, the way i initilize is splitted in two segments. Couldn't figure out how to map properly incoming data from database to FormControls hence i used 3 for loop to populate data. Is there any better way to do that? The piece of code i'm talking about is in the else {...} scope that is in initForm() method. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: great. check the edited code for refactor suggestion, so, move form creation into a separate method, and then create a default object, and then depending on `isEditMode` send either that default object, or fetch server object, so that in both cases form creator method receives the same payload object, and is constructed in the same, I'd leave the loops, but they could be moved to a separate method in the same manner